# How to make crontab interact with session of currently logged-in user?

Tags: cron, date, echo

**THE PROBLEM**

Crontab does work - but just aside, not in interaction with users.
How to make crontab talk to currently logged-in user by automatically perceivable prompt output? For example, a wake-up call, an alarm clock, ringing every minute for user1, without user1 having to do anything for receiving the message, except being present at the computer, with open eyes and ears?

**Side note**
The timing, every minute… - of course, this is just a technical example,
in reality a more meaningul and useful timing is chosen.

**IMAGINE THIS**

Computer = switched off

user1 = dave

dave:

```
*switching on computer*

*logs into his user account "dave"*

*lands in GUI desktop*

*starts mate-terminal*
```

*Checking who is logged in and what they are doing:*

```
dave@LocalMachine:~$ w
12:46:42 up  4:22,  2 users,  load average: 0.18, 0.44, 0.43
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
dave   tty7     :0               08:24    4:22m  6:57   0.31s mate-session
```

*Creating executable bash script "alarm_clock" in /tmp/*

```
dave@LocalMachine:~$ emacs -nw /tmp/alarm_clock && chmod +x /tmp/alarm_clock
#    Alarm clock displaying current time and ringing.
#
#    Copyleft     2024
#
#    This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
#    it under the terms of the GNU Affero General Public License as published by
#    the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
#    (at your option) any later version.
#
#    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the
#    GNU Affero General Public License for more details.
#
#    You should have received a copy of the GNU Affero General Public License
#    along with this program. If not, see <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
#
#!/bin/bash

# Passes 2 things to standard output of whoever is executing this script:
## string "current date" - by part $(date)
## acoustic alarm signal - by sequence \a within "" of echo behaving differently by set -e option
echo -e "$(date) \a"
```

*Creating crontab with 1 cronjob for him alone,*

*with an alarm clock ringing every minute,*

*expecting a prompt of current time while job execution on screen and an alarm sound,*

*as if he had given standard input into mate-terminal bash `echo -e "$(date) \a"`*

```
dave@LocalMachine:~$ crontab -e
#
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').#
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
#
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
#
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
#
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
#
# m h  dom mon dow   command

# Variables
## Otherwise will spill out "TERM environment variable not set." as 2
### It is set - but just for user "dave", not crontab itself
#### … until now:
TERM=xterm

# Test
## sh-file "alarm_clock"
### executable for dave, dave (group) & others
### containing shebang bash
### containing NEWLINE as last character of the document
### working when being executed by dave
### redirecting standard output, split up into results.log for successful parts, and errors.log for errors
* * * * * /tmp/alarm_clock > /tmp/my_command_results.log 2>/tmp/my_command_errors.log
```

**THE OUTPUT**

```
dave@LocalMachine:~$ tail -f /var/log/syslog
Jan  2 13:52:01 LocalMachine CRON[9786]: (dave) CMD (/tmp/alarm_clock > /tmp/my_command_results.log 2>/tmp/my_command_errors.log)
Jan  2 13:53:01 LocalMachine CRON[9807]: (dave) CMD (/tmp/alarm_clock > /tmp/my_command_results.log 2>/tmp/my_command_errors.log)
Jan  2 13:53:28 LocalMachine kernel: [19747.884955] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:38:43:7d:3a:bd:51:08:00 SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=26121 PROTO=2 
Jan  2 13:54:01 LocalMachine CRON[9813]: (dave) CMD (/tmp/alarm_clock > /tmp/my_command_results.log 2>/tmp/my_command_errors.log)
Jan  2 13:55:01 LocalMachine CRON[9818]: (dave) CMD (/tmp/alarm_clock > /tmp/my_command_results.log 2>/tmp/my_command_errors.log)
Jan  2 13:55:33 LocalMachine kernel: [19872.884504] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:38:43:7d:3a:bd:51:08:00 SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=26123 PROTO=2 
Jan  2 13:55:46 LocalMachine com.canonical.indicator.sound-gtk2[1651]: ** (process:2001): WARNING **: music-player-bridge.vala:262: Could not create a desktopappinfo instance from app: firefox.desktop
Jan  2 13:55:46 LocalMachine com.canonical.indicator.sound-gtk2[1651]: ** (process:2001): WARNING **: music-player-bridge.vala:181: Could not create app_info for path firefox
Jan  2 13:55:46 LocalMachine com.canonical.indicator.sound-gtk2[1651]:  Getting out of here
Jan  2 13:56:01 LocalMachine CRON[9857]: (dave) CMD (/tmp/alarm_clock > /tmp/my_command_results.log 2>/tmp/my_command_errors.log)
```

```
dave@LocalMachine:~$ emacs -nw /tmp/my_command_results.log 
-e Tue  2 Jan 14:01:01 CET 2024 ^G
```

**side note**

That `^G`, that's unexpected.
Can't explain to me where that comes from, judging the script just contained
a simple `echo -e "$(date) \a"` and passing this manually into mate-terminal bash gives standard output `Tue  2 Jan 14:06:57 CET 2024` + a popping sound as alarm signal.

**Now it becomes even weirder**

Having realized I've took a look into that file with en editor, instead simply invocing `cat`, I've repeated with process with the latter, triggering strange output

```
dave@LocalMachine:~$ cat /tmp/my_command_results.log
-e Tue  2 Jan 14:11:01 CET 2024
```

**PLUS** a popping sound as alarm signal, as if I hadn't invoced `cat` but an `echo` like for example `echo -e "$(date) \a"` ! How weird is that?!

my_command_errors.log is empty either way:

```
dave@LocalMachine:~$ cat /tmp/my_command_errors.log
dave@LocalMachine:~$ emacs -nw /tmp/my_command_errors.log
dave@LocalMachine:~$
```

**TEST PHASE 2: IMPLEMENTATION**

*Now with that all out of the way, dave is switching the crontab active,
by creating a copy of the line, removing the part redirecting the output into files, away from standard output, and commenting the copy source out*

**Before**

```
dave@LocalMachine:~$ crontab -e
```

```
* * * * * /tmp/alarm_clock > /tmp/my_command_results.log 2>/tmp/my_command_errors.log
```

**After**

```
dave@LocalMachine:~$ crontab -e
```

```
# * * * * * /tmp/alarm_clock > /tmp/my_command_results.log 2>/tmp/my_command_errors.log
* * * * * /tmp/alarm_clock
```

**THE OUTPUT AFTER ACTIVATION**

```
dave@LocalMachine:~$ tail -f /var/log/syslog
Jan  2 14:28:02 LocalMachine CRON[10175]: (dave) CMD (/tmp/alarm_clock)
Jan  2 14:28:02 LocalMachine CRON[10174]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Jan  2 14:28:53 LocalMachine kernel: [21872.877424] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:38:43:7d:3a:bd:51:08:00 SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=26155 PROTO=2 
Jan  2 14:29:01 LocalMachine CRON[10182]: (dave) CMD (/tmp/alarm_clock)
Jan  2 14:29:01 LocalMachine CRON[10181]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Jan  2 14:30:01 LocalMachine CRON[10191]: (dave) CMD (/tmp/alarm_clock)
Jan  2 14:30:01 LocalMachine CRON[10190]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Jan  2 14:30:58 LocalMachine kernel: [21997.876838] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:38:43:7d:3a:bd:51:08:00 SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=26157 PROTO=2 
Jan  2 14:31:01 LocalMachine CRON[10195]: (dave) CMD (/tmp/alarm_clock)
Jan  2 14:31:01 LocalMachine CRON[10194]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Jan  2 14:32:01 LocalMachine CRON[10202]: (dave) CMD (/tmp/alarm_clock)
Jan  2 14:32:01 LocalMachine CRON[10201]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

Aside of missing redirection output no changes, still everything is quiet in the room with the computer, although according to syslog the cronjob is executed every minute. And a prompt of the current date as if the user manually types in `echo "$(date)"` and then RET, doesn't appear either. Silence on all channels.
How can that be? And more important: **What to change for automatically receiving a popping sound as alarm signal every minute and display of current time of that event on the screen?**

Comment: From `man ascii`: 007   7     07    BEL '\a' (bell). The terminal renders `BEL` as`^G` (BEL is octal 007, G is octal 107).

Comment: `cron` explicitly runs jobs in the background. stdin is from /dev/null, stdout and stderr are saved and (by default) emailed to the user. The job does not inherit a terminal (there may be no logged-in user at all, and how would you set window focus anyway). Sound is less restrictive (I can `* * * * * spd-say -r -60 -p -50 -i -40 Doh`).

Comment: `cron` is not meant to interact with users, and your usecase doesn't sound like a job for `cron`,

Comment: [_Cron job not running_ on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743548/cronjob-not-running)  has an answer by me with some ideas around this question. In brief, "not even wrong".

Comment: Note: the bash script doesn't start with `#!/bin/bash` in the first line. I doubt the kernel will execute it (but it can still be executed as a parameter to `bash`, but not in your case).

Answer (score 0):

### `^G` character

First of all, when you do `echo '\a'`, the bell is being sound by the terminal that received it. It's just an ASCII code with the octal value of 007. It is also equivalent to press CTRL+G (`^G).

from man 7 ascii:

```
       Oct   Dec   Hex   Char                        Oct   Dec   Hex   Char
       ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
       000   0     00    NUL '\0' (null character)   100   64    40    @
       001   1     01    SOH (start of heading)      101   65    41    A
       002   2     02    STX (start of text)         102   66    42    B
       003   3     03    ETX (end of text)           103   67    43    C
       004   4     04    EOT (end of transmission)   104   68    44    D
       005   5     05    ENQ (enquiry)               105   69    45    E
       006   6     06    ACK (acknowledge)           106   70    46    F
       007   7     07    BEL '\a' (bell)             107   71    47    G
```

Usually this character is not visible:

```
$ echo -e "$(date) \a"
Tue Jan  2 18:31:38 IST 2024
```

But you can see it by adding the `-v` / `--show-nonprinting` flag to `cat` command (*use ^ and M- notation, except for LFD and TAB*):

```
$ echo -e "$(date) \a" |cat -v
Tue Jan  2 18:31:40 IST 2024 ^G
```

So when you just write this ascii code to a file - and not to a terminal - you will just write the value of octal 007 char to the file. Only when you write it to a terminal you'll hear a "beep" sound.

### `-e` not used by `echo`

Another problem you have with your script, is that it doesn't start with the Shebang (`#!`), but with a comment. In that case your `#!/bin/bash` is ignored, and the script will probably be executed by `/bin/sh`. See `man 5 crontab`:

> Several  environment  variables are set up automatically by the
> cron(8) daemon. SHELL is set to /bin/sh [...]

`/bin/sh` on your machine might be some POSIX adherent shell in which the `echo` builtin that doesn't support the `-e` flag (which is not defined by POSIX and is usually just an extension). In that case, it will use the `-e` as part of the string you want to echo. If you want to make sure you use `bash`, move the comments to **after** the Shebang.

Also, for this case it's better to use `printf`, for instance: `printf "$(date) \a\n"`

### Sending the message to an actual terminal

As we said, when you write it to a file, you don't interact with any terminal, you just write some character to a file. If you want to send the message to a terminal, it's better to use [`write(1)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/write.1.html), which will send the message to the last active tty of a user. For instance:

```
printf "$(date)\a\n" | write <USER>
```

At which case the user will receive a message on his active shell such as:

```
Message from root@locahost on pts/0 at 19:00 ...
Tue Jan  2 19:00:49 IST 2024 
EOF
```

Or if you want to send the message to ALL users and terminal, use [`wall(1)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/wall.1.html).

```
printf "$(date)\a\n" | wall
```